# AES > Base64 Encryption/Decryption and 256bit mode

Tags: c++, encryption, base64, aes

I need to create a internal AES/Base64 encrypt system for my application.
I mean , I don't want to have any side dll for my exe like openssl library.

I found this threads :

- [Problems with CryptoPP C++ AES-256+Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130498/problems-with-cryptopp-c-aes-256base64)
- [Crypto++ encrypt and decrypt in two different c++ programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000688/crypto-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-two-different-c-programs)

But they wasn't what I need  , I searched and I found nothing.

What I need exactly is like this site : https://aesencryption.net/

1. First an AES encryption with a key at 256bit mode
2. Next convert it to Base64 ( a Result of encryption in base64 in **aesencryption.net** )
3. And a decrypt system to get the first string from encrypted result.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130498/problems-with-cryptopp-c-aes-256base64) the key has to be 32 lenght but in the aesencryption.net it can be everything .

Can you please guide me how can I create a system like aesencryption.net site ?

Comment: Off topic either: Too broad (write my code) or Asking to recommend. Please edit your question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RichardCritten hi Richard , No i don't need any code I need guide . like included libraries , links or anything can help me . thanks

Comment: You can compile OpenSSL as a static library.  Please do not plan on writing your own AES implemention. http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html (See the slide labelled "Foot-shooting prevention agreement".)

Comment: @RichardCritten I will do an edit

Comment: @SamuelHardson - well I've voted to close as too broad.  Please [edit] your question to clarify you want recommendations for suitable libraries, and we can close it as being "off-topic: requests for library".  Sorry, but SO had rules about what is on-topic here, and this question isn't.

Comment: @MartinBonner my bad , I respect the community . please do what is right.

Comment: To help you with your Base64 stuff, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180947/base64-decode-snippet-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1